# Sendgrid Ruby API, Trying to send over Header content in post request

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, http, saas

I am trying to send over a Post request to sendgrid to generate an API key for a subuser.

This is what my code currently looks like

```
body = JSON.parse('{
                "name":"My API Key", 
                  "scopes": [
                    "mail.send",
                    "alerts.create",
                    "alerts.read"
                  ]                 
              }')  

header = {'On-Behalf-Of' => 'my@email.com'}

sg = SendGrid::API.new(api_key: ENV['SENDGRID_API_KEY'])
response = sg.client.api_keys.post(request_body: body, request_header: header)
```

This code generates the API but on the main account instead of the Subuser account. The header is what drives where the API key is generated and I can seem to find any sources online that how the correct syntax for sending over the header to sendgrid.

If you could please help I would really appreciate it. Thanks!

Comment: What happens when you run this code?  Do you get a syntax error?  Do you get an exception?  Do you get a failure response from the API?

Comment: Who's credentials are you using in there? https://sendgrid.com/docs/Classroom/Send/How_Emails_Are_Sent/how_do_i_send_mail_through_subuser_accounts.html

Comment: @Mirv I am using my api key and in the header is where i would specify what subuser i want to generate the api key for but for some reason all it does is create the api key under the main account. Im pretty sure im passing it incorrectly if they are doing nothing with it.

Comment: @WayneConrad there is no error. It succeeds and I generate an api key for the main account. It is not taking into account the header

Comment: It would be good to edit the question and add those details to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recently had to do this. You need to set the `On-Behalf-Of` headers when you instantiate the client not when you make the request:

```

```
@send_grid = API.new(api_key: @api_key, request_headers: {
               'On-Behalf-Of' => @username
             })
```

```

Then when you make a request with `@send_grid` it will send on behalf of the subuser -- and the API key will not show up in the list of api keys on the parent account

Answer (score -2):

If I understand correct, you want to send email "From" another user. On Behalf of is non standard way of doing things. 
For eg. https://sendgrid.com/docs/Classroom/Troubleshooting/Authentication/my_emails_are_displaying_as_on_behalf_of_or_via_in_some_mail_clients.html

You may want to try setting `from` instead of `on-behalf-of`

`"from": {
    "email": "from_address@example.com"
  },`

Refer to: https://sendgrid.com/docs/API_Reference/Web_API_v3/Mail/index.html